# Invalid operands to binary expression ('BOOL' (aka 'signed char') and 'void')

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

Ive been working on iphone app and since beta for 7.1 came out, I could not compile app for 64bit devices I am getting an error:

**"Invalid operands to binary expression ('BOOL' (aka 'signed char') and 'void')"**

problem was that previous version of app uses google anaytics v2 and that one is not supported in new iOS, but I followed their sdk and their "migrating" manual to v3, but I can't make it to work, here is a problem:

previous code that was working

```
BOOL returnValue = YES;
    if(tracking1) {
        id tracker1 = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:tracking1];
        [tracker1 setCustom:1 dimension:con];
        [tracker1 setCustom:2 dimension:mod];
        returnValue &= [tracker1 sendView:screen];
    }
    if(tracking2) {
        id tracker2 = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:tracking2];
        [tracker2 setCustom:1 dimension:con];
        [tracker2 setCustom:2 dimension:mod];
        returnValue &= [tracker2 sendView:screen];
    }
    return returnValue;
```

according to Google's manual I changed to this new code

```
BOOL returnValue = YES;
    if(tracking1) {
        id tracker1 = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:tracking1];
        // Set the custom dimension value on the tracker using its index.
        [tracker1 set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1] value:con];
        [tracker1 set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:2] value:mod];
        [tracker1 set:kGAIScreenName value:screen];

        // Send the custom dimension value with a screen view.
        // Note that the value only needs to be sent once, so it is set on the Map,
        // not the tracker.
        returnValue &= [tracker1 send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];

    }
    if(tracking2) {
        id tracker2 = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:tracking2];
        // Set the custom dimension value on the tracker using its index.
        [tracker2 set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1] value:con];
        [tracker2 set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:2] value:mod];
        [tracker2 set:kGAIScreenName value:screen];

        returnValue &= [tracker2 send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView]  build]];
    }
    return returnValue;
```

and my returnValue &= [tracker...] is being highlighted and shows me an error that I've posted.

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: What's the return type of the `send:` method? It bet it is `void`.

Comment: I am not quite sure, I am trying to find that one out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`send` method in `GAITracker.h` doesn't return anything:

```
/*!
 Queue tracking information with the given parameter values.

 @param parameters A map from parameter names to parameter values which will be
 set just for this piece of tracking information, or nil for none.
 */
- (void)send:(NSDictionary *)parameters;
```

Just remove the assignations `returnValue &= ...`